# I am trying to store data in database using PHP but it's not connecting with this

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am a beginner in PHP and trying to store data in MySql but there's problem while storing data, that data not entering in the database.

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost"; // usually is localhost
$db_user = "root"; // change to your database password
$db_password = " "; // change to your database password
$database = "dictionary"; // provide your database name
$db_table = "dict"; // your database table name

$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root',’’); //root is a default user and password usually blank
mysql_select_db($database,$db); ?>
<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST['Submit'])) {
$ sql = "INSERT INTO $db_table(eword,hword) values ('".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['eword']))."','".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['hword']))."')";
if($result = mysql_query($sql ,$db)) {
echo "<h1>Thank you</h1>Your information has been entered into our database<br><br>";
}
else {`enter code here`
echo "ERROR: ".mysql_error();
}
}?>
```

Comment: *"i am beginner in PHP"* -- the best thing to do if you want to learn something is to throw away any tutorial you find using the old [`mysql_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) functions. The `mysql` extension is deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed from PHP 7.0. Go forward and learn PHP database programming using [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO mysql`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

Comment: Is there an error?  How specifically is this failing?  Can you debug to find the exact query being executed?  Is it what you expect it to be?  What happens when you execute that query manually on the database?

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: You have a typo... `$ sql` should be `$sql`.  Turn on error reporting and PHP will show you errors like that.

Comment: Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\newdb\storedata.php on line 8
Not connected : Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Have you checked your cridentials?

Answer (score 0):

Database connection made with this code..
the code is used for fetching data from database & display on window directly..

```
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); //The Blank string is the password
mysql_select_db('your_database_name');

$query = "SELECT * FROM your_table_name"; //You don't need a ; like you do in SQL
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<table>"; // start a table tag in the HTML

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
echo "<tr><td>" . $row['your_first_column_name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['your_second_column_name'] . "</td></tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
}

echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML

mysql_close(); //Make sure to close out the database connection
```